# How do I pass generic interface as parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, interface

I have an `IParameter<WrapperInfo>` variable, where `WrapperInfo` only contains a name and a type(Wrapper Type). And I have 4 `ITypeWrapper<T>` class implementations contained in the same namespace (`StringWrapper`,`BoolWrapper` etc.).

I'm sure `WrapperInfo.Type` is an `ITypeWrapper<Type>`, and I want to instantiate one of that type, and be able to use `ITypeWrapper<Type>`'s methods and properties.

I do know that I can do this with reflection and dynamics, but I just do not wanna have all code that done way, that is terrible.

EDIT: I get those `IParameter`'s as `IParameter[]` as a parameter for a delegate.

EDIT 2: I can change any logic.

Comment: Consider rearchitecting the entire thing so parameter sets are a `Dictionary<string, object>` with the runtime type of the value indicating the type, or (depending on what exactly the code's doing) a `Dictionary<string, Type>` to describe parameter types. Your scenario sounds a lot like using generics because it's possible, not because it adds any actual type safety.

Comment: But the thing is.. I don't want objects, I want the actual type instead. My reason for doing these is avoiding typecasts everywhere, but I couldn't make it.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but If I try to instantiate with the type variable, I can only get object without having knowledge of what the type will be.

Comment: Well, that's how statically typed languages work. If you know the type at compile time, you can use it. If you don't, you can't. Generics don't change that, they just make it possible to do type safety more easily by ensuring that objects have the same type without repeating identical chunks of code. If you want to invoke code but you don't yet know what code it's going to be, you can choose: delegates, virtual methods, reflection, `dynamic` or a `switch` on the type. Generics generally only really help with the packaging. (There are cases where they actually help performance too.)

Comment: I just want to store `ISomeInterface<T>` as a variable without `T` being object, but I can't make it. That's why I can't just use switch or something like that. I cannot return value of `ISomeInterface<T>`

Comment: `ISomeInterface<int>` and `ISomeInterface<bool>` are types - you can assign them to a `Type` variable. But even then, what do you do with it? Once you get the `Type` you'd have to inspect it to see what the generic argument - `int`, `bool`, etc. - is. Once you go down the dark road of abandoning type safety, forever will reflection and inspection dominate your destiny.

Comment: I will call methods on them, they are all type specific. And that is what I wanna avoid.

Comment: What about `IParameter<WrapperInfo<T1>, T> where T:ITypeWrapper<T1>`? I've gone down this path before, and I gave it a name: "The Generic Rabbit Hole of Madness."

Comment: But I get parameters as a list, so I'm not sure if I can do that.

Comment: The literal answer to your question is to pass a `Type`. A generic interface is a `Type`. But the second part of the question involves how do you instantiate an object, knowing only its type, and then use its properties and methods, all without reflection. You just can't. That's the point of static typing. You should always be able to interact with an object based on its declared type. If it's declared type isn't enough and you need to inspect it further to figure out what it is so you know what to do with it, something has gone wrong.

Comment: I can actually use reflection, but I think it is a really bad way. I can instantiate an object of given type, but it stays as an object, which does not have a favour me. But I think the final solution is, adding a switch to the type and doing the business that way.